# How to enable strict conversion of json.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

Here is my dto of action for json input :

```
public class GreetRequest
{
    public string Message{get;set;}
}
```

When the json is post from the client:

```
{
    "Message":true
}
```

the json.net would convert the Boolean to string automatically:

```
true -> “true”
```

By far，I wrote a converter to enforce the rule:

```
public class StrictStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
       readonly JsonSerializer defaultSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType.IsStringType();
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           switch (reader.TokenType)
           {
               case JsonToken.String:
               case JsonToken.Null:
                   return defaultSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
               default:
                   throw new JsonSerializationException();
           }
       }

       public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }

   public static class JsonExtensions
   {
       public static bool IsStringType(this Type type)
       {
           type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) ?? type;
           if (type == typeof(string))
               return true;
           return false;
       }
   }
```

the converter is configure at startup.cs

```
 services.Configure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(options => { 
                    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StrictStringConverter());
                });
```

Question:

1. Is there any out of box way of strict conversion for json input, without writing any converter manually.

Comment: I've removed the misleading tags from your question (they relate to Framework, not Core). I've also removed the tag from your title as it contravenes tagging guidelines.

Comment: What you are doing is the only way to enable strict string deserialization, there's no flag in `JsonSerializerSettings` to disable this behavior.  One improvement to suggest: if `reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String` you can just return `(string)reader.Value`, you don't have to do a nested deserialization.